# Capillary action only works with glass tubes?

Tags: physical-chemistry, capillary-forces

I tried to reproduce the capillary action and measure how high the water rises. So far, I've tried unsuccessfully with a regular drinking straw and a very narrow plastic tube with an internal diameter of about 0.5mm. Does the tube have to be glass for it to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Few things in chemistry are truly unique. The tube does not have to be glass; it only has to be ***wettable***, which glass typically is and plastic typically isn't.

In the tubes made of non-wettable materials, capillary action works *the other way*: the liquid will go down rather than up, akin to Hg on the picture provided.

[image: Capillary action] ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action))

So it goes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it with the glass tube inside a weather thermometer.